# Sitecore 8 Installation Guide

Tags: installation, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to install Sitecore 8. I got an error saying "SQL Server Version Not supported - SQLServer (10.50.1600.1)" I tried to find installation document to know database requirements. I could not find anywhere, may be i am looking in wrong place.

[doc.sitecore.net](https://doc.sitecore.net)

[kb.sitecore.net](https://kb.sitecore.net/)

Could some one point me out in right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it finally,

For someone like me searching the whole internet here is the link

[Sitecore 8 installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_8_0/Non-secure/InstallationGuideSC80A4.ashx)

Comment: The Sitecore Compatibility Table is also a useful link https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164 to see what is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [How To Install and Configure Sitecore](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-install-and-configure-sitecore/) for the complete guide on installing latest version of sitecore.

Sitecore 8.1 has a specific requirement for the operating system, IIS web server, .Net framework and the database server. Follow the detail sitecore guide for installing the sitecore properly.

IIS Requirements for Sitecore 8.1

- IIS 8.5
- IIS 8.0
- IIS 7.5
- IIS 7.0

.NET Framework and Database Requirements for Sitecore

To install Sitecore 8.1 you would need minimum version of .net framework 4.5 and above. Sitecore requires miminum MS Sql server 2008 R2 SP1 or above editions like SQL server 2012, SQL server 2014  and MongoDB Database 2.6x

Answer (score 0):

The site appears to be in beta, so the accepted answer is no longer working.

It appears that the best recommendation, as of now, is to view the general [Sitecore 8 downloads page](https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/), find the version you want documentation for, and then scroll down that version's page to find the documentation.

Given how hard it is to find the Sitecore 8 page (I had to search their new beta community forums), I much prefer the old SDN site.